# How do you use GPUImageMovieComposition from GPUImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I can't figure out how to use GPUImageMovieComposition with GPUImageMovieWriter (from [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)), are there any examples on how to use it?

Here's what I've tried, I've tested that the composition, videoComposition, and audioMix are are valid:

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovieComposition alloc] initWithComposition:composition andVideoComposition:videoComposition andAudioMix:audioMix];
filter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];

[movieFile addTarget:filter];

GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[filter addTarget:filterView];

NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)];
[filter addTarget:movieWriter];

movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
    [movieWriter finishRecording];
}];
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance replacing your instantiation of movieWriter with this one helps?

```
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:fileURL size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0) fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie outputSettings:nil];
```

Further question, does the movie file play on the device correctly and you are just having no luck storing the file?

If so, is it because you are looking for the file in iTunes under the "apps" tab, but you didn't set the `Application supports iTunes file sharing` flag over in "Custom iOS Target Properties" to `YES`

If both of those are way off, what exactly isn't working for you?